# What is MDX "not in" SQL's analog for where clause?

Tags: ssas, mdx

In SQL I can write this:

```
SELECT some_column_1, some_column_2 FROM some_table WHERE some_column_3 NOT IN ("blah", "bleh", "meh");
```

How to do the same in MDX? Notice that **some_column_3** is not selected, but acts as filter.
I know about **EXCEPT** thing in MDX, but I can use it only for something that selected on axes. How to put it in **WHERE** clause? Or how to get same result with something else?

For example, I need something like this:

```
SELECT some_measure ON COLUMNS FROM [Model] WHERE some_hierarchy NOT IN ("blah", "bleh", "meh");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Except` function or its abbreviation `-` (minus sign) like this:

```
SELECT [Measures].[some_measure] ON COLUMNS 
FROM [Model] 
WHERE {-{[Some Dimension].[some_hierarchy].[blah], [Some Dimension].[some_hierarchy].[bleh], [Some Dimension].[some_hierarchy].[meh]}}
```

Comment: ... WHERE EXCEPT([Some Dimension].[some_hierarchy].[some_hiearcrhy], { [Some Dimension].[some_hierarchy].&[blah], [Some Dimension].[some_hierarchy].&[bleh], [Some Dimension].[some_hierarchy].&[meh] }); Is this also correct?

Answer (score 1):

IN MDX if you want all members of a dimension attribute except any particular member you use the following syntax

Dim1.attrubute1.children - Dim1.attrubute1."member value you dont want"

So your query gets transformed to

select 
([measures].[column1])
on columns,
(
[dim1].[column2].children
)
where 
([dim1].[column2].children - {[dim1].[column2].[blah],[dim1].[column2].[bleh],[dim1].[column2].[meh]})